# Can't start ssh service: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server

Tags: 20.04, ssh

Can't start ssh service:

```
Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. You need to add considerable more detail in order for anyone to help you out. In your question, you need to include the exact steps you took before this error appeared. It seemed you changed the configuration, because `/usr/sbin/sshd -t` exits with an error, and this only validates the configuration. Also, please include the entirety of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in your question. Thanks.